# Aspect oriented programming: slow in c#

Tags: aop

I tried AOP example at http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/3
It works well but I am having a problem with performance.
Each call now has 40ms overhead.

Is there a way to
1. Reduce the overhead? Not sure if there is things that can be removed from the example.
2. More importantly, have the call interception done for public methods only? I can look at Type inside Preprocess but at that point, I’ve already used 20ms and I would like private methods to not be intercepted at all. I can do that by making the attributetargets to methods but I would rather avoid that and leave the attributetarget to class.

Thanks

Comment: Which AOP tool are you using? It looks like maybe Aspect# or DynamicProxy based on that series of articles?

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective it is not a good idea to use `MarshalByRefObjects`for implementing AOP. There ar a lot of other good AOP implemetations wich have a much better performance because they use code generation to implement the aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Even with MarshalByRefObjects, performances are acceptables if you intercept few calls. 40 ms seems to be a very bad overhead caused by implementation of "advice" and not only  interception process.

You can try compile time AOP Framework like PostSharp but if you have an issue with "the way advice is implemented" it will not solve your case.

If you want to compare you can try [NConcern .NET](https://github.com/Virtuoze/NConcern), a runtime lightweight AOP Framework with good performance and easy to use.